# OverlayTrigger into div

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I need to use this OverlayTrigger:

```
<OverlayTrigger placement="top" delayShow={500} overlay={<Tooltip id={pc.id + 
"_dateIntervalTooltip"}>{formatInterval(pc.validFrom, pc.validTo)}</Tooltip>}> 
{eventHistory.userCreated}, {moment(eventHistory.dateCreated).fromNow()} 
</OverlayTrigger>
```

And I need to put it into this div:

```
return (
  <div className="event-history">
          <div className="eh-header-left">
            <EventCatIcon/>
            <div className="text">{lovLabel(eventHistory.eventType)}</div>
          </div>
          <div> 
          HERE I NEED TO USE OVERLAYTRIGGER
          </div>
        </div>
```

It doesn't work when I use it like this:

```
 return (
      <div className="event-history">
        <div className="eh-header">
          <div className="eh-header-left">
            <EventCatIcon/>
            <div className="text">{lovLabel(eventHistory.eventType)}</div>
          </div>
          <div> <OverlayTrigger placement="top" delayShow={500} overlay={<Tooltip id={pc.id + "_dateIntervalTooltip"}>{formatInterval(pc.validFrom, pc.validTo)}</Tooltip>}>
                {eventHistory.userCreated}, {moment(eventHistory.dateCreated).fromNow()}
                </OverlayTrigger>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Can you share the error as to what you get when you try to do this, also in order for the community to help you out try replicating this issue in codesandbox.io and share the repo link here.

Comment: It doesn't show any error. Just the app has been still loading

Comment: Try replicating your codebase on codesandbox.io and share the repo link from there. In order for people to help you out.

Comment: Generally just saying "it doesn't work" won't generate many helpful replies. Please try to be more specific in your question and maybe take some time to read the help area to get an idea how to ask a great question.